# Prevent PHP File Showing

Tags: php, fwrite

The following code receives strings from an HTML page and writes the strings to a text file. However in doing so it opens up a page in my browser with the address of the php file.

How can I stay with my html page and prevent this other page from showing.

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['txtFile'];
    $tbx = $_POST['tbx'];
    $chk = $_POST['chk'];
    $txa = $_POST['txa'];

    $file_handle = fopen($name, "w");

    fwrite($file_handle, $tbx . $chk. $txa);
    fclose($file_handle);
?>
```

The HTML form posting to this page is:

```
<form action="troncon.ca/Test/Test1.php"; method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="dataUpload">
  <input type="hidden" name="txtFile" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="tbx" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="chk" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="txa" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: can you post the code for your 'html page'

Comment: This allows your user to write any file on your system. Probably not what you want.

Comment: My HTML code for the above is as follows:<form action="http://www.troncon.ca/Test/Test1.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="dataUpload">
  <input type="hidden" name="txtFile" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="tbx" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="chk" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="txa" value="">
 </form>

Answer (score 2):

Send a [204 No Content response](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.5) using the [http_response_code function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php).

```
<?php
http_response_code(204);
exit;
```

or in older versions of PHP

```
<?php
header('HTTP/1.1 204 No Content', true, 204);
exit;
```

> ## 204 No Content
>
> The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to return an
>   entity-body, and might want to return updated metainformation. The
>   response MAY include new or updated metainformation in the form of
>   entity-headers, which if present SHOULD be associated with the
>   requested variant.
>
> If the client is a user agent, it SHOULD NOT change its document view
>   from that which caused the request to be sent. This response is
>   primarily intended to allow input for actions to take place without
>   causing a change to the user agent's active document view, although
>   any new or updated metainformation SHOULD be applied to the document
>   currently in the user agent's active view.
>
> The 204 response MUST NOT include a message-body, and thus is always
>   terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.

Comment: I've tried adding your suggested code but it has no effect.

Comment: I assume I just include it at the end of my existing php code?

Comment: Assuming that your existing PHP code doesn't output any content - yes.

Comment: OK. I've got it to work. I used: header("HTTP/1.0 204 No Content");

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use an AJAX request to submit the data in the background. If your form is submitting directly to this script, then the browser's address WILL change to the script's.

On another note, do **NOT** use this script. You are directly allowing a user to specify a filename (including path data) **AND** its contents. A malicious user can use this code to COMPLETELY subvert and take over your server. It is a **HIDEOUS** security hole.

Answer (score 0):

Just not close php tah in end of file - interpreter will understand that this file should not have any output:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['txtFile'];
$tbx = $_POST['tbx'];
$chk = $_POST['chk'];
$txa = $_POST['txa'];

$file_handle = fopen($name, "w");

fwrite($file_handle, $tbx . $chk. $txa);
fclose($file_handle);
```

Thats all.

Comment: This won't work. PHP will deliver a 200 OK text/html response with a zero byte body if you do this (and the browser will render a blank page).